# TclOO : Rename method

Tags: tcl

I would like to rename a method `foo` to `Foo` but keep the old method (`foo`) to avoid renaming all methods already used. 
I think that configuring my object with this function `renamemethod` *fromName toName* is not the solution in my case since this solution will remove my old method. 
I wanted to do that, but I’m asking if that’s correct :

```
method foo {args} {
    # do something... with $args
}

method Foo {args} {
    # The first letter in capital letter...
    my foo $args
}

export Foo
```

I don’t think it’s pretty, but I don’t know how else to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `forward` command:

```
forward Foo my foo
```

Do you think that is prettier?

Comment: Oh !! yes it's prettier , thanks @Schelte Bron

Comment: This might be the picky monk in me, but the example should read: `forward foo my Foo`, this matches the OP's intention: discontinue `foo` without breaking callers.

Comment: In the code shown by the OP, the `foo` method is still doing the work. `Foo` only invokes `foo`. For that situation, the `Foo` method should be replaced by the `forward Foo my foo`. If the `foo` method is actually renamed to `Foo` as stated in the description, then I agree with you that `forward foo my Foo` would be the correct command to use.